# Best way to do quick animation

Tags: sprite-kit

Hello So I have a game with animated crack textures that will appear sort of randomly thought the game.  Their are about 5 animations with 5 frames each.  So far I have been using SKAction move through array of SKTextures however I am wondering if their is a way I can put all 5 frames on one image and just change the texture coordinates.  Is this possible in sprite kit?